# Can I run docker without root in github actions?

Tags: bash, docker, github, github-actions, root

I don't want to use root, for safety, so I did as VSCode suggests, here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

# non root user (https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-nonroot-user)
ARG USERNAME=dev
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

USER $USERNAME
```

I pass the current directory on github workflows:

```
 docker run -u dev -v $PWD:/home/dev/project project /bin/bash -c "./my_script.sh"
```

but `my_script.sh` fails to create a directory with permission problems. I also tried `docker run -u $USER ...` but it does not find the user `runner` inside the container.

One option is to run with root: `docker run -u root ...`, but is there a better way? I tried passing `docker run -u dev ...` but I get Permission Denied also.

Comment: you can try to use podman instead of docker, it is nearly the same in term of running dockerfiles, but it do not requires root access. See https://podman.io/getting-started/installation how to install it

Comment: Rootless podman would only make access to a host volume more difficult.

Comment: What does `my_script.sh` do?  Can you `RUN mkdir ...` in the image to do whatever setup it needs to do, before switching to an unprivileged `USER`?  (As @BMitch's answer suggests, this `sudo` setup is not especially secure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ````
>     && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
>     && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME ```
> ````

Those two lines defeat the entire reason for not running your container as root. It's a passwordless escalation to root making the user effectively the same as having full root access.

> ```
> docker run -u dev -v $PWD:/home/dev/project project /bin/bash -c
> "./my_script.sh"
> ```
>
> but my_script.sh fails to create a directory with permission problems.

Host volumes are mounted with the same uid/gid (unless using user namespaces). So you need the uid/gid of the user inside the container to match the host directory uid/gid permissions.

> I also tried docker run -u $USER ... but it does not find the user
> runner inside the container.

If you specify a username, it looks for that username inside the container's /etc/passwd. You can instead specify the uid/gid like:

```
docker run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" ...
```

Make sure the directory already exists in the host (which will be the case for `$PWD`) and that the user has access to write to that directory (which it should if you haven't done anything unusual in GHA).

Comment: why does VSCode uses/suggests those lines then?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I probably don't know since I'm not a VSCode dev, but which lines are you asking about? And did this answer solve your issue?

Comment: " Those two lines defeat the entire reason for not running your container as root"

Comment: from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-nonroot-user

Comment: "[Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting."